# What does it mean for propositions to be in parenthesis without logical operators.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

i have stumbled upon this on one of my schools automatized tests.

In my universities discrete math 1 module:
"Let P and Q be logic expressions, applying the laws of calculus prove the following:"
(P v Q)(~P v  Q)<=> Q

Do I multiply them? I can't find anything like this in any of my books.

here are some screenshots
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfV4D.png)

[supposed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7sGy.png)

Comment: The multiplication is just "and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer $(P+Q)(\bar{P}+Q)$ rather than $(P \lor Q)\land(\lnot P \lor Q)$. Hence, the logical steps follow:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(P+Q)(\bar{P}+Q) \, = & \, \overbrace{P\bar{P}}^{0}+PQ+\bar{P}Q+QQ &\\
 =& \, \underbrace{(P + \bar{P} + Q)}_1 \, Q  &\\
= & \, Q & \blacksquare
\end{aligned} \end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @dexfrg $(P+Q)(\bar{P}+Q)$ and $(P \lor Q)\land(\lnot P \lor Q)$ are both standard, whereas the given proposition (omitting the $\land$ symbol and writing 'or' as $\lor$ ) isn't.